# Как правильно сделать новую версию api если изменился только ответ(Response)

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

Попросили поменять формат ответов на всех эндпоинтах, для этого я сделал новую версию апи и скопировал контроллеры с первой версии во вторую, просто заменив ответы, есть ли какие-то более элегантные способы это сделать, просто если будут какие-либо изменения, нужно будет менять в двух местах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить заголовок в запрос, который будет отвечать за необходимый формат ответа. Тема самым если добавится 3,4,5... версии, то все что будет нужно сделать, реализовать новый тип ответа.

Comment: Получается, нужно добавить if else чтобы в зависимости от того есть заголовок или нет определять какой формат ответа давать для каждого эндпоинта?

Comment: Да, можно так, но лучше https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/strategy